# Send notification on status bar when service is complete

Tags: android

I have an app that is using services to download images, but I wish to notify the user when the downloads are complete even when the user is outside the app(a notification in the status bar) also that works in minSdkVersion="8", I know there are some answers about this but I don't get the notification works: here are some of my code (it works only the notification is the problem):

```
public class saveJsonContact1Service extends IntentService {

    private static FileOutputStream fos;

    private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;

    public saveJsonContact1Service() {
        super("saveJsonContact1Service");
      }

    @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        downloadImages();//To download images


        sendNotification();//To send a notification after the donwloadImages() method has ended

      }


      private void sendNotification(){

          CharSequence sns = "content";
          CharSequence sns2 = "content";

          NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification = new Notification(/* your notification */);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, sns, sns2, pendingIntent);
                notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
      }
      }
```

How can I modify the sendNotification()??
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void sendNotification(){

    CharSequence title = "The title";
    CharSequence message = "My message";

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                      .setAutoCancel(true)
                      .setContentTitle(title);

    mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    mBuilder.setTicker(message);
    mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    NotificationManager notificationManager =   
           (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```